# How can I create Property in domain class that won't be added in table when I run migration

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, entity-framework-migrations

I want to use Confirmpassword property in my domain class to check user enter correct password, But I think when I will run migration it will aslo create Confirmpassword column in table. How can i add this property without adding it to my table in domain class ?

Comment: [What is ViewModel in MVC?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11064316/what-is-viewmodel-in-mvc)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My opinion is that you shouldn't add this property in your domain class. You should have a **View Model** instead to hold all extra information and perform the checks. Try to learn more about the View Models in mvc.

For future reference; you can always exclude a property in your domain class from becoming a table column by adding `the NotMappedAttribute`:

```
public class Foo
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [NotMapped]
    public int SomeProperty { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Thank's Kostas, NotMapped attribute worked and I got what i wanted. And now I also know use of viewmodel and that will be very useful .